# Dynamic RLS in power BI with security table and hierarchy

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to wrap my head around dynamic rls in power bi and have this requirement which I haven't found documentation on.

I have a security table. ie

[image]

and a Location Hierarchy table ie,

[image]

this means that for every user they can either have access to a City, State, Country or everything (all).
In my dataset, we only know the City, and I need to implement rls using this to grant access to the relevant locations.

something like, look at the security table and get all values for the user, if say the return value is Australia then return any City where the City or State or Country is Australia.

Is this achievable within power BI?